# software-properties-gtk only runs with sudo (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, python, gtk

I have a problem where `software-properties-gtk` will error out when I try to open it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 245, in __init__
    self.init_distro()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 424, in init_distro
    distro = current_distro()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/utils.py", line 72, in current_distro
    releases = di.get_all(result="object")
AttributeError: 'UbuntuDistroInfo' object has no attribute 'get_all'
```

For some reason, when I run `sudo software-properties-gtk`, it runs flawlessly. However, when I try to open the desktop app or run it without sudo, it would give me the error above.

I have already tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal`, and although there are tons of questions concerning software-properties-gtk here, none of them seem to match this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I came across this reddit post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/qyxq6t/softwarepropertiesgtk_wont_execute_due_to_python/

Their solution of running

```
python3 -m pip uninstall distro-info
sudo apt reinstall python3-distro-info
```

worked!